# passing arguments to igraph function within sapply

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to network analyses and ERGM models and have a list of lists which has 100 Erdos Renyi Models as content and was created with the code below

```
set.seed(666)
gs <- list()
for (x in seq_len(100L)) {
  gs[[x]] <- erdos.renyi.game(374, 0.0084, type = "gnp", directed = F)
  E(gs[[x]])$weight <- sample(1:5, ecount(gs[[x]]), T)
}
```

Now I would like to calculate the mean path length between two nodes as well as the average clustering across these 100 models.
For the mean path length I used the following code:

```
random_mean_paths <- sapply(gs, igraph::mean_distance, 1:100) 
mean(random_mean_paths)
```

However, if I try the same with `igraph::transitivity` , i.e.

```
random_mean_clus <- sapply(gs, igraph::transitivity, 1:100)
```

I get the error

```
Error in match.arg(arg = arg, choices = choices, several.ok = several.ok) : 
  'arg' must be of length 1
```

and when trying to resolve this error by setting `type = "global"`, i.e.

```
random_mean_clus <- sapply(gs, igraph::transitivity(type = "global", 1:100)
```

I get the error  `argument "graph" is missing with no default`

I cannot specify `gs` in the `transitivity()` function, since it is not an igraph object and I am stuck trying to pass the correct argument to this function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Any of

```
random_mean_clus <- sapply(gs, igraph::transitivity, type = "global", 1:100)
random_mean_clus <- sapply(gs, \(s) igraph::transitivity(s, type = "global", 1:100))
```

will solve the problem.

The first includes the named argument in the arguments list and the second defines an anonymous function, `\(s)` using the new way introduced in R 4.1.